# Send two pieces of data via Jquery AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm sending data via Jquery Ajax post, I want to send the text box from my form, but also a variable called username.
For example...

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'submit.php', data:$('#myform').serialize(), username});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: one way would be to programatically add a username input to the form before you serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the extra parameter to the serialized string

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'submit.php', 
    data:$('#myform').serialize()+'&username='+encodeURIComponent(username)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, it is better to construct a data object and also include the extra variables. Try constructing a data object and include them ?

```
data = {
    'formData': $('#myform').serialize(),
    'variable': 'username'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the query below. username should be a js variable.

```
var username = "myname";

$.ajax({
 type:'POST', 
 url: 'submit.php', 
 data:$('#myform').serialize(), 
 username:username
});
```

Comment: In PHP for the form I accessed the serialized data with $_POST['text_box_name'], $_POST["username"] doesn't seem to exist with your code, what will it be called?

Comment: Should be $_POST['username']

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$.ajax({ 
  type:'POST', 
  url: 'submit.php', 
  data:$('#myform').serialize(), 
  username: username //you missed the key
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it your other variable via get like this.

`$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'submit.php?myvar='+encodeURIComponent(myvar), data:$('#myform').serialize(), username});`

You could also add the value to a hidden field in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $.ajax({ 
         type:'POST', 
         url: 'submit.php', 
         data: { form: $('#myform').serialize(), username: encodeURIComponent(username)}
    });
```

check [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the part **Sending Data to the Server**